# Why won't my Patricians advance?

Tags: anno-1404

I have clicked every house i can find and they are all full green for taxes and for needs.  I've read numerous resources and almost everything points to getting everything in the green.

I'm so tired of this current game I need to finish it successfully!

Here is a screenshot of my citizens.  How can i get my patricians to advance to nobles and end this!

I even have envoys on my main island to facilitate my Patrician advancement, but i'm still stuck.

[image]

Comment: How many Nobles do you currently have?  It's been a while, but I think they're the pink bar; 3400?

Comment: Yes, the pink are nobles, at the top.  Patricians are blue and next down the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have enough people.  Only a certain percentage of your population can advance to the next stage, likely to ensure you don't leave all your industry looking for workers who think garbage collecting and making beer are beneath them.

The solution is simple: put down more houses.  You could even build another entire district, if you want to play it safe.  As you level up more of your population towards Patricians, it will allow them to move up to Nobles, and you'll win the level.

Comment: This link someone had the same question and one answer is that with 11k population it should be possible to get 5k nobles.  I'm at 14k population...
https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/952498-dawn-of-discovery/50364269

Comment: You need certain ratios to support higher levels of population.  A calculator I found says you need 2200 beggars to support 4000 nobles.  It's not just straight population, but the right ratios of population.

Comment: Seems you're right.  I maxed out my island and increased my nobles, but I simply can't reach 5k.  I'm guessing I have to wipe out the AI player and expand on his land.